# How to specify the right version of an assembly to use in MSBuild inline task?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, assemblies

I have an inline C# task that I'm writing in an MSBuild project. I'm running into some issues because the assembly I need to load references a type in an older version of .NET framework. How should I go about making MSBuild reference the correct assembly version?

Here's some code:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="HelloWorld" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
        <ConfigFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        <Environment ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build"/>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework"/>
        <Reference Include="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll"/>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>

        <Using Namespace="System"/>
        <Using Namespace="System.Xml"/>
        <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities"/>
        <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework"/>
        <Using Namespace="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Xml"/>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
            //obtain a list of environment nodes in the substitution config
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ConfigFile);
            List<String> envList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//environments/*").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            //envList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Nevermind what's in the CDATA block, I want to add more that uses MSBuild.Community.Tasks.

Unfortunately, after trying to build I get the following error:

> error : error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. c:\Users\charris\AppData\Local\Temp\i1wmm4q1.0.cs(24,57) : error CS0433: The type 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task' exists in
>   both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5\3.5.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a \Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5.dll'

So from what I understand, MSBuild community tasks relies on the type 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task' but I have two version of 'Microsoft.Build.Utilties' loaded in my appdomain. In normal C# applications, I could just use assembly binding redirection, but I'm not certain how I can reference the correct assembly here. Any help is appreciated!